# How to set crontab using command prompt?

Tags: cron

How to set cronjob/crontab in server using command prompt. Give sample command or sample links.

Answer (score 6):

```
crontab -e
```

edit crontab interactively with your default editor

```
crontab <file>
```

replace crontab with contents of given file

General usage help is displayed if you run crontab without arguments, for example:

```
crontab: usage error: file name must be specified for replace
usage:  crontab [-u user] file
    crontab [-u user] { -e | -l | -r }
        (default operation is replace, per 1003.2)
    -e  (edit user's crontab)
    -l  (list user's crontab)
    -r  (delete user's crontab)
    -i  (prompt before deleting user's crontab)
```

More help available via "man crontab".

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab -e
```

will work wonders when you’re trying to edit your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

The pimlottc's answer looks perfect(+1). But I will left you a link to a little tutorial because you asked for it.
[cron&crontab-howto](http://www.tech-geeks.org/contrib/mdrone/cron&crontab-howto.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this link here step by step explan how you can set cron using comman prompt. Its a very gud tutorial for me  ...  http://phpsollutions.blogspot.in/2014/02/set-up-cron-job-using-command-prompt.html

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. We prefer to have an excerpt with the relevant information from any links posted. Please edit your post to include the most relevant data from the link.